# Configuration Profiles applying as System Account instead of user

Tags: microsoft-intune, mdm

I'm pulling my hair out over an issue I'm having with Intune. I've deployed a VPN profile using a custom configuration profile to my users and most users have received the VPN profile on their laptops (W10) without any issue. Some however have not. When checking the devices belonging to the users who haven't received the profile, I see that they Intune policies seem to be applying with the System Account instead of the user.

An example of a working users device configuration status: [All policies successfully applied on the device using the primary users UPN.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gbxr.png)

An example of the device configuration status of a user who isn't receiving the VPN profile:
[Client settings are applied using the System account but the VPN profile (user setting) won't apply, stating 'Not applicable'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzz59.png)

The 'User status' of the VPN profile configuration profile is showing 100+ 'Not applicable' for System Account. So 100+ of my users aren't picking up the policy.
[119 instances of 'System Account' / 'No applicable'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KESfL.png)

Some example machines I checked are showing the correct primary user. The VPN configuration profile is targeting 'All Users'.

Any idea why this policy is applying to some users machines using their UPN (and succeeding) and some devices trying to apply the policy using the System Account (and not succeeding)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I created a new dynamic group to target just our active and licenced users. I have redeployed the policy to this group but it is only reporting as succeeded on the users who have already received it (which I'd expect), but still not applying to the others (119).
It's as if Intune cannot find the users to then apply the policy to. To test, I manually performed a dsregcmd /leave on a users machine and had them restart and sign in and out a couple of times to reenroll the machine. After this, the user picked up the policy successfully. I can't do this for the other 118 users though.